# Find what javascript changes the DOM?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I've been working with a ton of other's JS recently, and am starting to really hate trying to debug it.  Even with Chrome's dev tools I can't track down a lot of the DOM changes that are taking place during page load.

Are there any tools that will show me what part of the DOM (say an added attribute) was done by what JS?

Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In Chrome dev tools, you have the option of breaking execution when the DOM changes. [image]

Also a screenshot to illustrate Wolfram's answer (+1)

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to break on a subset of DOM elements using a selector? Thanks

Answer (score 25):

A minor addition to Jayraj's answer: [Breakpoints on DOM Mutation Events](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#dom). Right click on any element and you can select `Break on Subtree Modifications` and `Break on Attributes Modifications` and `Break on Node Removal`.

This is also possible using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel#Types): right click an element and you have some options to monitor it for changes.