# Is it possible to detect when an inline style property was set?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I have a bug where a certain div is having its style.height property being set to 0px by Javascript but I have no idea what code is doing this unwanted setting.

**Is there to tell the debugger to halt execution when the inline height property is set or for me to at least have an event fire when this occurs?**

The problem is occurring in a thorny inner loop and I don't want to have to do a manual "binary search" unless I really have to. (Specially since there is a chance that the culprit code could be coming from an event or timeout and that would be harder to pinpoint by hand)

Edit: I also need to be able to do this before the element in question is inserted into the main document. By the time I can do to the elements tab to inspect it the bug has already been triggerred.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find what javascript changes the DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268457/find-what-javascript-changes-the-dom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Elements tab of Chrome Dev Tools, I believe you can right click on the element and there should be an option to "Break on attribute modification".

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#dom

Comment: Hmm, for some reason I had forgotten that this worked for inner attributes. Do you know if there is a way to set this for elements that have not yet been included in the main document tree? (If I print the element in the console it only shows a "Reveal in Elements Tab" option but that doesn't do anything since it hasn't been inserted yet...)

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that. Does this element have an ID? If it does maybe you could use the Search scripts function in the Scripts tab and search for the ID, or maybe search for '.createElement' and start setting some breakpoints, you may get lucky.

Comment: neh, I did some tests and it turns out that the attribute monitoring only works on stuff that is attacked to the main document. I think temporarily attaching the node to the document body might do the trick though.