# Is there an easy way to find out by which js code a DOM element is manipulated?

Tags: javascript, debugging, dom

I was looking at a website and saw something interesting: a DOM element that was animated in an interesting way. I wanted to figure out how it was done so I started digging into the source code. It took me ages to track down the piece of code that did this.

Does anyone know of a way to sort of 'track' a DOM element so you can detect by what code it's being manipulated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find what javascript changes the DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268457/find-what-javascript-changes-the-dom)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Chrome, you can add DOM Breakpoints. You can find a more in-depth explanation [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#dom).

In short, you select the DOM element you want to inspect in the Elements panel and you select `Break On...` -> `Subtree Modifications`. When the DOM element changes its *structure*, you will be pointed to the JS code that does that.

<s>However, if you're specifically after the JS code that does animations, that could change only the CSS of the element, and as far as I know, there's no way to break on that.</s>

On the other hand, Chrome is also pretty flexible in letting you [break on JavaScript events](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#listeners) that happen in the browser. As [jfrej suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13027215/182629), you can see what action triggers the animation and break on that.

You can set the breakpoint to `Attributes modification` from the same element menu (`Break On...`) and it will also break on CSS changes. Thanks to [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) for the suggestion in the comments. Tried a [simple example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ES8Jp/).

Comment: +1, Thanks for your suggestion, in my case I'm afraid it's about css manipulation of a fixed DOM structure so it won't help me in this particular case, but it's very good to know about for other situations!

Comment: If the debugger is able to stop on `DOMSubtreeModified` events, it should be able to stop on `DOMAttrModified`, too

Comment: It is, you have that option on break on. But I don't know if that works for CSS style changes. Let me try. :)

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, JavaScript needs to use a selector of some sort to modify HTML structure or to apply CSS. Think what the selector might be - it's usually either ID or Class.

Firebug can do a search in multiple files - just go to the Script tab, focus in the search field and check *Multiple Files*. This way you should be able to find the piece of code that's targeting the DOM element.

Alternatively, if the animation is triggered by an event, such as a mouse click, you can use Chrome's Developer Tools to add Event Listener Breakpoints under the *Sources* tab, which will work in the same way as DOM Breakpoints described by [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13027005/206614).