# Is there a way to find all the javascript code that ran against a specific element selection?

Tags: javascript, debugging, css-selectors, developer-tools

I wonder if in Developer Tools or any other tool, there is the possibility to provide a selector, e.g "input.name.highlight" and track all the code that javascript ran against it in real time? Usually bad javascript/jquery code that is running using very generic selectors or selectors like $("input").not(".foo, .bar, .baz, .qux") or running on a global scope is difficult to track so I wonder if there is a tool that would automate debugging process by outputting the line numbers of the code that just ran against the selected elements.

Comment: That's not really a job for developer tools, you need to monkey-patch the `$` and `jQuery` functions, or add a break-point to them.

Comment: There should be a way through other tools to make it more generic. Well I wonder if there was a possibility to implement a debugger extension that will check each line of code of javascript not just jquery and see if the dom element that it affected is in the list of the ones that match the selector.. I would be interested to implement that somehow but I don't know where to start. It shouldn't be very difficult

Comment: I found this and it could be what I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268457/find-what-javascript-changes-the-dom - I made a comment if you can actually put a selector to filter to some dom elements and not any..