# see where a dom element is emptied by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

This is mostly a question about debugging ... i have a very big JavaScript file, that somewhere inside it , it removes (`empty()`) a certain element. i tried to check that element for id , class in the JavaScript but couldn't find it so maybe is using some other selector based on some logic.

The question : is there a way to see where a certain element with an id , is removed / emptied by chrome and pause at that line ?

Or is there a feature regarding this matter if somebody else had the same problem in the past ?

Comment: May this will help you [domManipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268457/find-what-javascript-changes-the-dom)

Comment: the thing is that ... this element is emptied once after the full dom loads .. so i can check it only on refresh ,.,..

Comment: Place a break point on document ready or any other place before the DOM is emptied and then when paused add the DOM breakpoint. I also remember DOM Breakpoint is persisted across page refresh too. But not too sure.

Comment: i tried that and is not

Answer (score 1):

You can set a breakpoint on DOM which would show the stack trace which modified the element.

**To set a DOM change breakpoint:**

- Click the Elements tab in chrome developer tools.
- Go the element that you want to set the breakpoint on.
- Right-click the element. Hover over Break on then select Subtree modifications, Attribute modifications, or Node removal.

More Information : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#dom

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Add a breakpoint on the node removal option, it might help you

Comment: yes but when i refresh ... i cannot see them setup . i can only test on refresh

Comment: ok ... after refresh that breakpoint is still on .. but it does not break .. and clearly the node is emptied .. i can see content for a split second inside that div .. and if i manage to stop the browser right in time i can see all content

Comment: the breakpoint will only fire if the element is removed, try adding subtree modifications,  that will watch through its childs