# Chrome: How can I find the javascript that's rendering a particular DOM element?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

I'm trying to debug an issue on a single page web app that is rendered using javascript. I'm mostly unfamiliar with how the page was built.

**Is there a way that I can detect how a particular element is being rendered, or at least when it's being added to the page?**

I'd like to set a break point for when the item is created or added to the DOM, or first rendered in the page.

I'm open to any solutions that preferably work in Chrome, like the `Chrome Developer Tools`, or `a debugging bookmarklet`, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find what javascript changes the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268457/find-what-javascript-changes-the-dom)